# VSTO: Changing Existing Word Ribbon Tabs

Tags: ms-word, vsto, ribbon

Using Visual Studio 2008 Pro, is it possible to make changes to the existing Word ribbon items?
For example, can I add an additional mail merge option to the "Finish" group in the "Mailing" tab?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, you can only add groups to built tabs, you can't add controls to built in groups.  If you want to add a group to a built in tab:

Visual Designer:
Set the ControlTypeId of the tab to Office and the ControlId to TabMailings, you can then add items to it like it were the Mailings tab

Ribbon XML:
just do something like this

```
<tabs>
   <tab idMso="TabMailings">
      <group id="MyGroup" label="My Group">
      </group>
   </tab>
</tabs>
```